# Add classes to form select option item

Tags: theming, forms

How can I add classes to a form option tag without JS?  At the moment in Form API I can pass a keyed array like this

```
array(
  '0' => 'option 0',
  '1' => 'option 1',
)
```

and I'll get html like this

```
<option value="0">option 0</option>
<option value="1">option 1</option>
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
array(
  array(
    'value' => 0,
    'text' => 'option 0',
    'class' => 'bob 0',
  ),
  array(
    'value' => 1,
    'text' => 'option 1',
    'class' => 'bob 1',
  ),
)
```

and then get this

```
<option value="0" class="bob 0">option 0</option>
<option value="1" class="bob 1">option 1</option>
```

Comment: Is this still an issue for drupal 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I wasn't able to get the fully flexible option done but here is a way to add classes to the `options` tag based on the option value.  It works but overriding the `theme_select` function to use my own version of `form_select_options`

```
// theme_select
function THEME_select($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'size'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-select'));
  return '<select' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . THEME_form_select_options($element) . '</select>';
}

/**
 *
 * @param type $element
 * @param type $choices
 * @return string 
 */
function THEME_form_select_options($element, $choices = NULL) {
  if (!isset($choices)) {
    $choices = $element['#options'];
  }
  // array_key_exists() accommodates the rare event where $element['#value'] is NULL.
  // isset() fails in this situation.
  $value_valid = isset($element['#value']) || array_key_exists('#value', $element);
  $value_is_array = $value_valid && is_array($element['#value']);
  $options = '';
  foreach ($choices as $key => $choice) {
    if (is_array($choice)) {
      $options .= '<optgroup label="' . $key . '">';
      $options .= THEME_form_select_options($element, $choice);
      $options .= '</optgroup>';
    }
    elseif (is_object($choice)) {
      $options .= THEME_form_select_options($element, $choice->option);
    }
    else {
      $key = (string) $key;
      if ($value_valid && (!$value_is_array && (string) $element['#value'] === $key || ($value_is_array && in_array($key, $element['#value'])))) {
        $selected = ' selected="selected"';
      }
      else {
        $selected = '';
      }
      $options .= '<option class="' . drupal_clean_css_identifier($key) . '"  value="' . check_plain($key) . '"' . $selected . '>' . check_plain($choice) . '</option>';
    }
  }
  return $options;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately this isn't very easy using the Form API currently.

There's an [issue](http://drupal.org/node/342316) open to add this functionality (it goes all the way back to 2008) that would theoretically allow you to do something like this:

```
$form['optiontest'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Option test'),
  '#options' => array(
    array(
      '#return_value' => 0,
      '#value' => t('First option'),
      '#attributes' => array('class' => 'first', 'title' => t('First option')),
    ),
    array(
      '#value' => t('Option group'),
      '#attributes' => array('class' => 'group', 'title' => t('This is an optgroup')),
      '#options' => array(
        array('#return_value' => 2, '#value' => t('1st sub-option')),
        array('#return_value' => 4, '#value' => t('2nd sub-option')),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

But unfortunately there are nothing but failed patches attached to the issue at the moment.

The only way I can think of to do it at the moment would be to add a [`#process`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#process) function to the select element, and add the class(es) to each option when they're broken down individually.

Answer (score -1):

There is actually a way to override individual `option` items, but it works with `checkboxes` and `radios`. I've been told that it doesn't work with `SELECT` though. Also, I'm not sure if it works in Drupal 7.

Here's some code that works in Drupal 8. Might be worth a try.

```
$form['select'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Select'),
  '#options' => [
    '0' => t('Bob 0'),
    '1' => t('Bob 1'),
  ],
  // You define attributes for individual options as follows.
  '0' => [
    // I have tried 'disabled' = TRUE and it works.
    'disabled' => TRUE,
    // I have never tried #attributes, but I think it should work.
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['bob-0'],
    ],
  ]
]
```

I hope it helps. Cheers! Alternatively, go for one of the other solutions.

Comment: looks like it is not working in D8...

Comment: Hmm. Then I guess I might've used it with `checkboxes` or `radios`.